# How to change sensitivity of proximity sensor on my phone

Tags: settings, 7.5

My Dell Venue Pro (DVP) often places calls on hold while I am actively participating in a call to other people.

I suspect that the proximity sensor re-enables the screen when I have the phone right up against my ear.

What can I adjust to make this problem go away?

P.S. My phone is carrier-unlocked, as I purchased it through Newegg.  I am running latest code, according to Zune.

Answer (score 2):

If your phone is under warrantee, swap it out. I know the phone can't support this natively, and I haven't seen an unofficial hack for the DVP either.

I guess your option at this point is to go to the [XDA forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/), and see if anyone knows if a registry setting. You will need an unlocked phone to do this though.