# Workarounds for failed proximity sensor (screen blanks out during calls)?

Tags: settings, htc

I've got the opposite problem to the one raised in [this question](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/801/how-to-change-sensitivity-of-proximity-sensor-on-my-phone) - the screen goes blank once a call is initialised and that makes it nearly impossible to end a call.

The phone's gathered plenty of dust and grime so I guess I've blocked/broken the sensor. There's a lot of online advice already out for this problem. Pressing in certain spots, clearing or cleaning the area of the sensor, holding the phone in certain ways ... none of these have worked for me.

The only workaround to control a call that I've found - short of removing the battery - is to use a bluetooth headset to end the call (proximity sensor is disabled when a bluetooth headset is connected).

Are there any better workarounds? I think I want to disable the sensor since it's clearly bust. Any way to do this? I'll take my chances with screen interference when holding it close to my ear.

**UPDATE:**
Curiously, six months later the proximity sensor has ... mostly ... started to function again meaning I can usually regain the screen in the normal way. Very curiously this coincided with picking up the 7.8 update. It couldn't be the update ... could it??

Comment: First try to reset your phone. That will help if its a software issue. This was an issue with lumia, you using the same??

Comment: HTC not Lumia. Since the phone *is pretty dusty* I have to assume I've grimed up the sensor and that it's not a software issue. I don't want to reset if I can help it, especially if it's unlikely to make any difference.

Comment: In lumia there was such an error for which the update was released. I guess you should consult HTC care. Hardware are the easiest to sort out. Just go to the care or local repair centre to restore the functionality. Right now, there is no way to disable the proximity sensor.

Comment: Is your phone Full unlocked or it has a custom ROM?

Comment: @VitorCanova what does that mean? It's unlocked in that it's not tied to a carrier and I can put any SIM in it. Is that what you mean?

Comment: So pressing the power button doesn't work (perhaps twice: once to the screen turn off and once to turn on)? I guess if you had a screen protector you have taken it off.

Comment: @hawbsl I mean something like jailbreak. In the way you can install app to change register keys.

Comment: @VitorCanova please see my new question

Comment: @hawbsl I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found another option if you don't have a bluetooth headset is to just push in some ordinary headphones during the call. This brings the screen back to life and you can end the call.

I guess if you don't typically carry headphones with you, you could just cut the end off some old headphones and carry the jack end around with the phone. Just insert to get the screen back at the end of a call. Still a pain but easier than removing the battery.

Answer (score 0):

My Lumia is having the same problem but I found out that to top of my screen is a bit raised. This causes (I guess) a gap for the proximity sensor and he then thinks that it's close to an object. To fix this I just hold the top of the screen and push it back for half a milimeter... I don't have time to bring the phone to service so I am using this approach.

I guess you will have to take it somewhere to be taken apart and cleaned